# Mobile version of phpMyAdmin - I know it is an interface

Tags: iphone, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am just after a mobile version of [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) - or another product.
I would like to access my database from my web browser as I often just need check on something.

The easiest way would be to use safari to access phpMyAdmin, but since I am on an iPhone it is hard to navigate that.

Is there a mobile version of that interface? Or some other product that does have one?

My searches have failed me to this day:-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out:

**Control Panel** by **Ollie Ket** in the Appstore, http://itunes.apple.com/app/control-panel/id339415513?mt=8 .

Also,

**CP Control Panel** by **Dayana Networks Ltd**. Also in the AppStore, http://itunes.apple.com/app/cp-control-panel/id437405473?mt=8

Comment: I have the Ollie Ket App - but it jsut shows the normal version UIWebView, no mobile version.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for just the same – and found this fine solution:

- [Adminer,](https://www.adminer.org/en/) a very small, single-file phpMyAdmin alternative plus
- [a plugin](https://github.com/pematon/adminer-theme) that makes it responsive and mobile friendly.

Seems to work fine, to be fast and good to use on the move.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to make a mobile theme for phpMyAdmin, I would not surprise if someone is making one using some CSS framework for mobile themes or something like jQuery Mobile or jQTouch, and surely he/she is getting a lot of pain with all the AJAX stuff in the source code.

Anyway, you can find a lot of iOS apps for managing MySQL databases:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-editor-pro/id414309098

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-database-client/id412789347

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-mobile-database-client/id397060484

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imysqlprog/id424343762

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-client/id490931147

Obviously all of them lacks of a lot of phpMyAdmin functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Navicat just released a mobile version of its MySQL database management  tool for iOS. It's Free and you can download at: https://itunes.apple.com/app/navicat-for-mysql/id688128940?ls=1&mt=8

Kevin

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s now insanely priced at € 21,99 (roughly 26 US$).